# Math videos featuring interesting data animations

Tags: nt.number-theory, stochastic-processes, recreational-mathematics, experimental-mathematics

I am looking for interesting videos featuring pure data animations (not someone talking about math, but a video featuring some math phenomenon). I am interested in videos that tell a story, rather than being pure art. I've seen some about fractals, or the orbit of the Riemann zeta function. But these are isolated examples. I am interested in a bigger, more comprehensive list of such videos.
Looking for videos bringing some insights and real math value (even if empirical), possibly featuring the result of some experimental math project. I produced a few. They show how chaotically the classic series of the Riemann function $\zeta(z)$ converges for specific values of $z$ in the critical strip. See one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H77ULp6HVsE). The picture below shows a Gif version.
[image]

My next question is how to add harmonious sound to the video, and I mean math-generated sound that matches the frames of the video, and is related to the concept being visualized. For instance, creating "Riemann zeta music". If you are aware of such videos, please let me know.

Note: I've found a webpage featuring some cool math-related animated pics: [www.reddit.com/r/mathpics/](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathpics/).

Comment: I made this animation recently https://youtu.be/16JCmLcVClE which shows a connection between simple physics and the exponential function, without words (although I also put a written explanation in the video description). Probably too elementary but I couldn't resist

Comment: for the harmonius sound, you might be interested in this : https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/tcamot/an_image_of_pitches_for_pitch_consonance/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share btw very cool animation. did you use sagemath and python?

Comment: @mathoverflowuser: thank you. In my case, it is the other way around: I have to create some mathematical music that will match the visual (Riemann zeta) pattern. I did it in R (to create the video frames and the MP4 file), but it is just as easy to do it in Python. The original data (partial sums of $\zeta$ in the complex plane) was produced in Excel! More about the technique at https://www.datasciencecentral.com/data-animation-much-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: To produce the GIF in my MO question, I used an MP4 to GIF converter. Plenty are available for free as online apps on the Internet.

Comment: @VincentGranville: Thank you for your comment. I will have a look a the link.

Comment: @VincenGranville: I must admit that my R knowledge is a little bit rusty. :-)

Comment: You might also enjoy this subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/generative/

Comment: @VincentGranville: I am no musician, but one approach would be to first create an integer sequence based on the visual Riemann zeta pattern and then create music based on this sequence, like here for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRwjTe6zm7s where the zeta function of the klein four group is sonified.